# initialising logger in one place like __init.py__

Tags: python, logging, config, init

I'm working on a project where I'd like to implement a logger. My structure is as:

```
.
├── mypkg/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── config/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── config.json
│   │   ├── config.py
│   │   └── logger.yml
│   ├── mod1/
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   ├── script11.py
│   └── mod2/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── script21.py
│       ├── script22.py
│       ├── script23.py
│       └── script24.py
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── tests/
```

Note up front: I have created links to the files for deeper investigation, but I believe everything should be understandable in one go, but the links are there for completeness.

However, I'm working on distributing and testing it, so I'd like a `fileHandler` for the first and a `consoleHandler` for the latter (defined in [`logger.yml`](https://github.com/GroenteLepel/qiskit-quantum-knn/blob/master/qiskit_quantum_knn/config/logger.yml)). I'm switching some stuff and settings around, so when I adjust the name of the logger, I'd like a place where I can simply change it quickly, instead of heading into each file and adjusting the logger command.

Right now, I'm using `config/` to save some configuration information. I do not really like this approach, and I would like to remove the folder entirely if possible. Right now, I read in the configuration the start of each `script**.py`, like `Config('config/config.json')`, where my `Config` is a class defined in [`config.py`](https://github.com/GroenteLepel/qiskit-quantum-knn/blob/master/qiskit_quantum_knn/config/config.py) for reading in `.json` files and translating it to a dict, and [`config.json`](https://github.com/GroenteLepel/qiskit-quantum-knn/blob/master/qiskit_quantum_knn/config/config.json) looks just like e.g.:

```
{
  "LOGGER": "consoleLogger"
}
```

So If I want to use the `consoleLogger` or `fileLogger` I simply change it in the `config.json` and I'm done. However, I don't like having a full config file around for simply this purpose, and was wondering if I could move the initialization which I have at the start of eacht `script**.py` as:

```
from mypkg.config import Config

config = Config("config/config.json")
logger = logging.getLogger(config["LOGGER"])
```

to e.g. the `__init__.py` in the `mypkg/` folder, or something like:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(`consoleLogger`)
```

I'd like your input on this.

Answer (score 1):

So the entire goal of initializing a `logger` like this was that it is suitable for a library, and eventually for releasing `mypkg` as a package. I've studied some more on the topic, and found a link via [The Hitchhiker's guide to Python](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/logging/#logging-in-a-library), referring to Python's [Logging HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library), which all state that defining handlers is always the case for the *user*, and not the *developer*. Thus, I have switched to initializing my loggers at the start of each file, using

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

which should create a [hierarchy of loggers](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial), e.g. `mypkg.mod1.script11` if this `getLogger` is called in `script11.py`. This, together with the fact that if no certain action is set for a logger, it will look at the settings of its parent. The user can now define a package-specific logger `mypkg`, or just simply define the actions of the `root` logger.

I've also added this to my `mypkg/__init__.py`:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

so that the user can simply use

```
from mypkg import logger
```

and configure the package-dependend logger to their own desires.

I have removed the entire `config` folder, since this was only there for my logger, which is now user-dependend on how that is configured, as it should be according to the style guides linked.